# Webpack project bundles and runs but nothing renders

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I've written a component in React Typescript (also using Next if that's relevant) and I'm trying to use it with Webpack. When I run the code, there are no console errors and it builds, but nothing renders at all. I put my main component in /pages/index.tsx. What am I doing wrong and how can I get my component to show up?

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
 entry: './pages/index.tsx',
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: ['babel-loader']
     },
     {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
     },
     {
       test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
       use: [
         {
           loader: 'url-loader'
         },
       ]
     },
     {  
       test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
       loader: "file-loader"
     }
   ]
 },
 resolve: {
   extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
 },
 output: {
   path: __dirname + '/dist',
   publicPath: '/',
   filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 devServer: {
   static: {
     directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
   }
 }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "widget",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --progress --color --port 3000",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.4",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "next/babel"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- to get the correct path, join the directories

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/",
  },
```

2- you need to add typescript preset to the `.babelrc`

```
"presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
```

3- Since you are not using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, you need to make sure that `index.html` is in the `dist` folder. and in `index.html` you have this line preferably at the bottom of `body` element

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

In single-page applications `index.html` is first sent to the browser and then the browser reads the `script` element since you set `publicPath: '/',`, it goes to the same directory which is `dist` folder to get the javascript bundle.

If you want to use [/html-webpack-plugin/ visit here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)